# Furniture turned purple, help?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, technical-issues, mods

All the small circle tables and most benches suddenly turned purple. How can I fix that (without restarting the game, I'm months into it)? I've been thinking about uninstalling and reinstalling all the mods, any other ideas?

**Mod information:**

- Flora pack, rewritten with hd textures 1.5 lite
- Static mesh mod (all 4 of them) 1.5 lite
- Pure waters (I know there's a better war mod, but couldn't install it)

All installed through Nexus.

**Graphics information:**

Using a beta NVidia driver, but I don't think that has anything to do with it, I'm sure one of the mods is at fault.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange Gaming. No capitalization, incomplete run-on sentences, terribad spelling - if only I had enough rep to edit without it needing to wait for review. Your school English teachers would cry. I suggest revising to make your question more readable, although I don't want to guess at the chances of an authoritative answer on this question even after some cleanup and I'll elaborate as to why.

Comment: Please post pictures of your house, it sounds hilarious.

Comment: This is sometimes caused by a texture failing to load into RAM. Does restarting the game fix this problem?

Comment: And by restarting the game, I'm sure ScouseChris also means closing and opening the game rather than starting a new game.

Comment: Whoops, I corrected that (or so I thought) @skovacs is quite correct

Comment: It's happend to me on this way and if you let it go, the game probably crash.

Comment: This cannot be "fixed" as "fix" implies correcting a problem, and if all your furniture is purple, there is no problem to be corrected.

Answer (score 3):

**Your purple tables result from a problem with the presentation of the table texture(s) - either they can't be found or can't be displayed by your graphics card.**

With so many individual mod packages installed, its could have been any that either overwrote the texture(s) or the code specifying the texture to use and to make it worse, there's no guarantee that uninstalling any of them will resolve it as their uninstaller may not reverse the change as it could have easily been from a failed install. Likewise, a graphics driver update, especially a beta, could also lead to your graphics card not rendering the table texture(s) properly and although this is not the more likely scenario, it is still a reasonable possibility. The game could have also glitched when you launched it either not loading the textures or experiencing some other error.

Because of the range of possible causes, I cannot guarantee any given solution, but I can provide you with the troubleshooting steps and solutions that I would attempt to find and resolve the problem. **None of these will have any effect on your saved games, but if you like, you can easily backup your saved games.** Take each of these steps in sequence to determine the cause of the issue:

1. **Close and re-open the game.** - if it simply errored and/or didn't load the texture(s), then this should fix the issue.
2. **Restart your computer.** - it could be an issue with what's loaded into RAM or some some related temporary memory issue and a simple restart should fix it.
3. **Uninstall each of your mods one at a time.** After you uninstall a mod, check to see if that fixed the issue. Stop if that fixes it, implying that the last mod you uninstalled was likely the source of the problem. - if a mod is the cause, then this may fix it, but there's no guarantees that the uninstallers will resolve it, but it is an option.
4. **Uninstall and re-install the game.** - If your game files have been modified or corrupted, this should resolve any issues there.
5. **Roll back the driver for your video card** - You should have a fresh install of he game by this point so all that leaves is the graphics driver. How far you roll back is up to you. I recommend the driver recommended by your original equipment manufacturer for your computer as they can support issues and make recommendations beyond that, but if you selected/installed the graphics card yourself, I would recommend rolling back to the last known working driver.

If these steps resolved your issue, you can work back from there to restore the setup with which you prefer to play. If you uninstalled mods and/or re-installed the game, you can try installing the mods one at a time, checking the game after each install to determine which was causing the problem. Once you determine which was the problem, you will likely have to go through the step above that fixed the issue (either uninstall the mod or uninstall and reinstall the game) and then restore your setup without that mod and you can search for assistance with that mod specifically. If you can restore your desired setup without reproducing the problem, then it is likely due to a failed installation at some point or something to that effect.

If these steps didn't resolve your issue, it would tend to indicate a more significant problem with your setup, be it a hardware issue such as faulty RAM or Hard disk errors, or an OS issue or something else entirely. Like I said, it's hard to be authoritative on this when there are so many things that could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some textures are missing in your skyrim install. I think the best course of action would be to uninstall the mods, verify your game files in steam (right click on the game -> properties -> game file -> verify game cache) then reinstrall your mods.

If it still doesn't work, You should try to reinstall your game. Your save game should not be changed by the reinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes for me as well (2x gtx 580's) but it usually resolves itself after around a minute.

As others have said, a reinstall will most likely take care of the issues permanently. Also make sure you are on the latest version of the game as well as all your mods.

Update all drivers. If this still does not work, I would say to uninstall your mods and see if it still is happening. If it is not, look for mod alternatives.

Good Luck!